# How do I fix a noisy humidistat/relay?

Tags: valve, humidifier, relay

I have a Rudd furnace with a Honeywell home humidistat.  It seems like when the humidity in the house get to the same setting that the humidistat is set to, that the relay opens and closes about a thousand times a minute making it sounds like a machine gun.  This goes on for 30-45 seconds each time and is very loud.  What do I need to replace to fix this?  Is it the humidistat or valve?

Comment: Please [edit] to indicate exactly which model numbers for the furnace and humidistat.

Comment: Has it ever worked properly?

Comment: I do not think it has ever worked but it is not very often where the actual humidity and the humidistat setting are the same, but when they are equal at 2:00 in the morning it is unpleasant.  I am away from him until mid march but when I return I will update with the exact model of the furnace and humidifier.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the humidistat. Apparently it lacks adequate [Hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis) if the valve remains closed or open when the humidity is far from the setpoint.

You should be able to test by removing the humidistat and connecting/disconnecting the wire manually (if it's a typical 24VAC system where that's not hazardous) or connecting them to a manual switch temporarily.

Comment: To clarify, connect the 24VAC to the valve, NOT the humidistat.  If the valve is working it will click once and once again when power is removed.   Then you know the humidistat is the problem.